# Matlab syms Function and integration

Tags: matlab

I have a sort of obscure question. I am wanting to do something with two separate set of syms and manipulate the syms. This is a little difficult for me to explain without including my code firsts so:

```
syms x Wg Iyy b
S = syms;
Pz1 = (Wg*n)/(2*b);
Vzx1 = int(Pz1,x,x,b)
Myx1 = -int(Vzx1,x,x,b)
dw_dx = (-1/(E*Iyy))*int(Myx1,x,0,x);
wx1 = int(dw_dx,x,0,x)

% Get the numerical output of the value using b as wing
clear S;
% assume(S,'clear');
% cellfun(@clear, S);    
L = 6;
b = (1490+10*L)/2;
Vzx1_num = Vzx1
Myx1_num = Myx1
wx1_num = wx1


% need to sub b for b=b_prime*cos(40)
% Not really sure how to do this, I know I have to redclare the syms

syms x Wg Iyy
```

So to expand on more what is going on and what I am looking to do. The first syms (syms = x Wg Iyy b), I would like to keep as is because based on my needs I want to output the value of Vzx1 in terms of those variables.  This part works perfectly for what I am intending to do.  The error lies in how I would like to manipulate the value I have generated. So secondly, I would like to ouput the numerical value of these generated expression by using the value of b. I am trying to clear the value of syms. 
When using

```
S= syms
clear S
```

The value of S gets clear. So b would no longer be a symbol and I can set the value of b, allowing Vzx1_num to ouput the value of Vzx1 with b replaced with a number. This is not the case as b remains a sym

Then thirdly I want to substitute the variable value of b for the value of b_prime*cos(40).  I have tried to mess with this but based on how I have previously declared b as a syms I am having a hard time manipulating this variable.  So when I use `syms x Wg Iyy`.  That is not the value of syms the value of syms outputs

> > syms
> >
> > Your symbolic variables are:
> >
> > Iyy       Myx1_num  Vzx1      Wg        wx1       x
> >     Myx1      Pz1       Vzx1_num  dw_dx     wx1_num

I am extremely confused why syms gets built using the values I have manipulated previously.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use [`clear(S{:})`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#bt09bdn-1), not `clear S`. The latter just removes the cell array returned by `syms`.

Comment: Does not work it.   Syms still gets built using the previously mentioned output